# How do I load the app name, app image and package name into variables I can use in a separate activity?

Tags: android, listview, variables, android-activity

I have this example application which I downloaded, which displays a list of apps on the phone. I am trying to study and learn the code but wanted to add to it by allowing you to click on an app and then toast the app name and package location.

Here is the source

```
    public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity {

    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();
        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
            Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);
            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } 

        Toast.makeText(AllAppsActivity.this, "You have selected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
             if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info);
             }

        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(AllAppsActivity.this, R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(AllAppsActivity.this, null, "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is ApplicationAdapter.java

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;

public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.appsList = appsList;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (null == view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
    if (null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
        ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));

    }
    return view;
}
};
```

Here is the xml for the listrow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yolo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you want to do exactly? i do not understand.

Comment: Get the app name, app image and app package location into variables, that I can use in a different activity I launch. So when I click on like browser, it launches a seperate activity which displays the app name, image, package location, and information I type about the app

Comment: ok then go to Intent and pass information between the Activity.Go to this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your onListItemClicked you can call the getItem method in your adapter. From that you can get the fields you need and can pass them as arguments to your new activity. By the way are you sure you need a new activity? It's possible you could just swap out fragments.

Comment: i think user is working on `Activity`. so Edit your Answer as per   that need

Comment: All my advice given is for activity? I just recommended another approach that might simplify things over having two activities if you're just changing views.

Comment: I need to show that I can launch a new activity based on a selected list item choice. So kinda.

Ill have a look at your suggestion though and comment again if I need any help. :)